# Chrome Timeline flame chart colors

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

What are the meanings of the Chrome Timeline flame chart colors?

I've found documentation for the Timeline waterfall colors, and for the Profiles flame chart colors, but not for the Timeline flame chart colors.

Comment: I would also like to know. The chart seems interesting but doesn't give much info on what exactly is going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you enable JS profile, it shows JS call stacks.

Each downloaded script is assigned its own unique color.

Each stack element is colored the color of the script that contains the function for that stack element.

When you disable JS profile, the four major colors are the same as for waterfall:

- Blue: network / loading / html parsing
- Purple: css / layout
- Green: painting / compositing
- Yellow: JavaScript execution

Comment: Where did you find this info?  I bet that that documentation contains a lot of other useful info.  Also, thanks for info.

Comment: A doc on major colors is here: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/timeline The colors of JS stack frames can be found in the source code https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/devtools/front_end/timeline/TimelineUIUtils.js&q=WebInspector.TimelineUIUtils.colorForURL&sq=package:chromium&type=cs&l=1757

Comment: Thanks.  I had already found the docs for the major colors, but not the source for the JS stack frames.  Source as documentation from a project led by the most valuable company on earth... I think they just might have the funds to hire a few more technical writers... :)